# Wordpress - how to make a custom page template dynamic

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-wordpress-pages

I'm using Wordpress to create a site with a number of custom page templates. I'm using html5blank as the parent theme. I need to move the page content from the text file over to Wordpress pages so it can be available to be edited in the CMS but I'm not sure how to create the correct loop / template tag for the code.

Here's a page example -

**template-meettheteam.php**

```
<?php /* Template Name: Meet the team */ ?>
<?php get_header(); ?>


    <section id="team">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="twelve columns">
                             <h4>MEET THE TEAM</h4>
                <div class="row">
                        <div class="four columns">
                                <img src="http://localhost:8888/wp-content/uploads/2017/07/tim.jpg" alt="Meet Tim" style="width:100px;height:100px;">
                                <p>Praesent sodales, leo at pellentesque pellentesque, nunc erat dapibus nunc, ut congue libero lorem in orci. Suspendisse potenti. Quisque facilisis mauris in vestibulum tempor.</br>Praesent sodales, leo at pellentesque pellentesque, nunc erat dapibus nunc, ut congue libero lorem in orci. Suspendisse potenti. Quisque facilisis mauris in vestibulum tempor.
                                </p> 
                        </div>        
                        <div class="four columns">
                                <img src="http://localhost:8888/wp-content/uploads/2017/07/tim.jpg" alt="Meet Tim" style="width:100px;height:100px;">
                                <p>Praesent sodales, leo at pellentesque pellentesque, nunc erat dapibus nunc, ut congue libero lorem in orci. Suspendisse potenti. Quisque facilisis mauris in vestibulum tempor.</br>Praesent sodales, leo at pellentesque pellentesque, nunc erat dapibus nunc, ut congue libero lorem in orci. Suspendisse potenti. Quisque facilisis mauris in vestibulum tempor.
                                </p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="four columns">    
                                <img src="http://localhost:8888/wp-content/uploads/2017/07/tim.jpg" alt="Meet Tim" style="width:100px;height:100px;">
                                <p>Praesent sodales, leo at pellentesque pellentesque, nunc erat dapibus nunc, ut congue libero lorem in orci. Suspendisse potenti. Quisque facilisis mauris in vestibulum tempor.</br>Praesent sodales, leo at pellentesque pellentesque, nunc erat dapibus nunc, ut congue libero lorem in orci. Suspendisse potenti. Quisque facilisis mauris in vestibulum tempor.</p>
                        </div>    
                </div>

                <div class="row">
                        <div class="four columns">    
                                <img src="http://localhost:8888/wp-content/uploads/2017/07/tim.jpg" alt="Meet Tim" style="width:100px;height:100px;">
                                <p>Praesent sodales, leo at pellentesque pellentesque, nunc erat dapibus nunc, ut congue libero lorem in orci. Suspendisse potenti. Quisque facilisis mauris in vestibulum tempor.</br>Praesent sodales, leo at pellentesque pellentesque, nunc erat dapibus nunc, ut congue libero lorem in orci. Suspendisse potenti. Quisque facilisis mauris in vestibulum tempor.</p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="four columns">    
                                <img src="http://localhost:8888/wp-content/uploads/2017/07/tim.jpg" alt="Meet Tim" style="width:100px;height:100px;">
                                <p>Praesent sodales, leo at pellentesque pellentesque, nunc erat dapibus nunc, ut congue libero lorem in orci. Suspendisse potenti. Quisque facilisis mauris in vestibulum tempor.</br>Praesent sodales, leo at pellentesque pellentesque, nunc erat dapibus nunc, ut congue libero lorem in orci. Suspendisse potenti. Quisque facilisis mauris in vestibulum tempor.</p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="four columns">    
                                <img src="http://localhost:8888/wp-content/uploads/2017/07/tim.jpg" alt="Meet Tim" style="width:100px;height:100px;">
                                <p>Praesent sodales, leo at pellentesque pellentesque, nunc erat dapibus nunc, ut congue libero lorem in orci. Suspendisse potenti. Quisque facilisis mauris in vestibulum tempor.</br>Praesent sodales, leo at pellentesque pellentesque, nunc erat dapibus nunc, ut congue libero lorem in orci. Suspendisse potenti. Quisque facilisis mauris in vestibulum tempor.</p>
                        </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>                
    </section>



       <?php get_template_part('form'); ?>


<?php the_content(); ?>



<?php get_sidebar(); ?>

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

All of `<section id="team">` needs to be available on pages to be edited. Do I create 'the loop' in between the section tags, something like this -

```
<?php
if (have_posts()):
  while (have_posts()) : the_post();
    the_content();
  endwhile;
else:
  echo '<p>Sorry, no posts matched your criteria.</p>';
endif;
```

Or is there a more simplified way of doing this? I'm fairly new to Wordpress and I initially assumed all this was taken care of by just using `<?php the_content(); ?>` but obviously not. I'm sure there's a simple answer to this, any assistance is appreciated.

Comment: you can write code in your worpdress editor - just have the editor as "text" instead of "visual". 
the_content() only gets the editor. 
Else i think that you will need to create some fields - then you can control where the data from which field will be put in your template - You can use Advanced custom fields for that - shouldn't be to hard, and you will be able to use that template on different pages - like : "<section id="<?php echo get_field('your_custom_Id_field')"> etc.

Comment: There is of course a syntax error in my code suggestion : <section id="<?php echo get_field('your_custom_Id_field'); ?>"> - But I doubt that you would be copying it in anyway